# Are tag dispatching objects actually instantiated?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

Consider the following example:

```
class MyHeavyObject
{
    MyHeavyObject()
    {
        // lots of initialisation
        // ...
    }
};

template<typename T>
void RegisterObject(T)
{
    DoSomethingWith<T>();
}
```

Now, if I call

```
RegisterObject(MyHeavyObject());
```

will the compiler understand that `MyHeavyObject` is never actually used and optimise the call, or will an instance of the object be created?

I would be interested both in what the standard says and what compilers actually do.

Comment: I believe any rule that would allow the compiler to optomize it out would cause RAII type `locks` to be allowed to be compiled out...

Comment: the standard prohibits optimizing away a local object when the constructor is non-trivial, i.e. changing the effect of the program. but *anything* can be optimized away under the as-if rule. this means that you have a guaranteed effect, or lack thereof, and with respect to efficiency you just have to **MEASURE**.

Comment: what do you mean by "tag dispatching objects" in the title. does that have anything to do with your example. also, your wording "never actually used" indicates that there's something that can be misconstrued as usage, but your example does not show such, what is it.

Comment: Check out the "as if" rule. In your case, the standard doesn't prohibit a compiler from optimizing it out, but I don't know what compilers are actually capable of.

Answer (score 2):

> I would be interested both in what the standard says and what
>   compilers actually do.

A compiler is allowed to perform arbitrary changes as long as the observable behavior remains the same. That is known as the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

If and only if `MyHeavyObject`'s default constructor has no side effects that  alter the observable behavior of the program, the parameter and temporary might be optimized out.

It's sometimes hard for the compiler to spot that - it *may* optimize side-effect free code, it *may not*, depending on how far it decides to analyse, and how complex your code actually is.
I expect both Clang and GCC to correctly optimize the above code (provided `MyHeavyObject`'s default constructor is fairly simple), but I'd test it to be sure.